# React Native flatlist inverted

Tags: react-native

I have a flatlist that shows a messages chat. I want to start at the bottom of the flatlist (showing the most recent messages). I added 'inverted={true}' and 'data={data.reverse()}' as the props.
It is sort of working, but the data alternates being reversed and not reversed every time i leave and enter the chat again.
Anyone know the fix?

[Attached code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJmSb.png)

Comment: Show the code. You are probably calling reverse on every single render but it's impossible to know.

Comment: Btw you likely don't actually want to reverse the data, as the first element of the list will already appear at the bottom

Comment: <FlatList
                data={data.reverse()}
                inverted={true}
And then i have the normal renderItem function for the messages

Comment: I have just added the code

Answer (score 0):

`.reverse()` mutates the original list.
If you do want your list reversed, do it like this

```
const App = ({ data }) => {
  const reversed = [...data].reverse(); // Make a shallow copy, then reverse the copy
  return <Flatlist data={reversed} inverted />;
};
```

However, you will probably notice that you don't want your list reversed, because inverted is already reversed.

```
const App = ({ data }) => {
  return <Flatlist data={data} inverted />;
};
```